# CasperJS - How to Skip to next test suite?

Tags: javascript, testing, casperjs, ui-automation

I'm quoting this [example](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/master/samples/googletesting.js):

```
casper.test.begin('Google search retrieves 10 or more results', 5, function suite(test) {
    ...
});
casper.test.begin('Casperjs.org is first ranked', 1, function suite(test) {
    ...
});
```

While executing the first test suite in this example, how do I skip to the test suite? I want to jump to "Casperjs.org is first ranked" test suite in the above example?

Or in other words, is there a way to skip to the next available `casper.test.begin()` block?

I have tried out [`test.skip()`](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/tester.html#skip) and the given documentation doesn't give me ideas on how to achieve the above.

Comment: You mean skipping the next `casper.test.begin` block from the previous one?

Comment: Yes. Skipping to the next available casper.test.begin block

Comment: Did my answer help solve the issue? Are there any problems with it?

Comment: @ArtjomB. I am still thinking about this, and havent had the time to try out your answer. Will check and get back on this

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with the public API that is provided by CasperJS.

Having said that, CasperJS' tester module manages the test cases in a [queue](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/668732235f49274092132650dc0bd9901f7c5955/modules/tester.js#L122). So you can simply call

```
test.queue.shift();
```

to remove the next `test.begin()` block or

```
test.queue.splice(1, 1); // second block after the next one
// position ----- ^  ^
// amount of blocks -´
```

to remove any future block. Note that this won't work for if the test cases themselves are not asynchronous. That is also why I used a `casper.start().then().run()` combo in the proof of concept.

**Warning:** This is not documented and may change in future versions.

Proof-of-concept:

```
casper.test.begin("test 1", function(test){
    casper.start().then(function(){
        test.assertTrue(true);
    }).run(function(){
        test.done();
    });
});

casper.test.begin("test 2", function(test){
    casper.start().then(function(){
        //test.queue.splice(0, 1);
        test.queue.shift();
        test.assertTrue(true);
    }).run(function(){
        test.done();
    });
});

casper.test.begin("test 3 (invisible)", function(test){
    casper.start().then(function(){
        test.assertTrue(true);
    }).run(function(){
        test.done();
    });
});

casper.test.begin("test 4 (visible)", function(test){
    casper.start().then(function(){
        test.assertTrue(true);
    }).run(function(){
        test.done();
    });
});
```

Output:

```
Test file: skip_begin_block.js
# test 1
PASS test 1 (NaN test)
PASS Subject is strictly true
# test 2
PASS test 2 (NaN test)
PASS Subject is strictly true
# test 4 (visible)
PASS test 4 (visible) (NaN test)
PASS Subject is strictly true
PASS 3 tests executed in 0.226s, 3 passed, 0 failed, 0 dubious, 0 skipped.
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following solution:

```
casper.start(url, function () {
  this.thenBypassIf(my_condition, 1);
});
casper.then(function() {
  // This step will be ignored if the above "my_condition" is true.
});
```